# Does Microsoft Test Manager have image recognition? (Like HP UFT/QTP's Insight?)

Tags: qtp, mstest, mtm

Does Microsoft Test Manager have image recognition? Anything like HP UFT/QTP's Insight?
If not, what would be some work around to get Microsoft Test Manager to have image recognition?

Insight is a feature in QTP/UFT that allows for detection of any kind of entity on an application based on finding that entity from a user defined stored image.

I used it to detect control elements from a VB6 application, which were unable to be "detected" on QTP (and all of UIAutomation/UISpy for that mater).

Thanks

Comment: I'm not completely certain that I agree with the downvote.  Phillip, could you maybe try to clarify a little bit more as to what you want for people who may not be familiar with UFT Insight?  Are you looking for a way to compare images?

Answer (score 1):

Actually not. Microsoft Test Manager is a simple T. management tool which allows you to run a Test case and report a bug into TFS, built on the top of Visual studio. It would be probably possible to plug it in, but usually there is nothing like this.

There are several test frameworks and automated test tools build on the top of visual studio as Ranorex, so it is definitely possible. But not out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to the MTM/CodedUI ecosystem that does what you're looking for.  I'm assuming that you're doing record/playback in MTM which is really generating CodedUI tests.  Have you tried building a UI map for these problem controls in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can capture a window image, save it and compare it to one stored on disk easily.

Something like this

http://bartwullems.blogspot.ca/2013/11/coded-ui-tests-automatically-take.html

Comment: please provide more infos and not only a link

Answer (score 0):

No there is not with CodedUI/TFS but we have found a way! Using Sikuli (open source) , there is a library compatible with .NET we integrated that to our project and it's working perfectly so far!